# PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I am getting this error when I am querying on a table with JSON column.

> PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar

**Table structure**

```
create_table :certificates, force: true do |t|
  t.column   :completions, :json
  t.datetime :created_at,  null: false
  t.datetime :updated_at,  null: false
end
```

**Query**

```
WITH completions AS (
  SELECT *, json_array_elements(completions) AS completions_json
  FROM certificates
)
SELECT * from completions;
```

Comment: The `json` in `certificates.completions` does not appear to be a JSON array.

Comment: This is the data [{"id":56,"date":"2016-08-09T07:46:04.555-04:00"},{"id":58,"date":"2016-08-09T07:46:04.555-04:00"}]

Comment: In *all* rows of `certificates`?